# htaccess code for custom directory rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

right now i currently have this script that's working

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

and this does exactly what i want. it displays:

```
example.com/userid
```

instead of

```
example.com/profile.php?username=userid
```

but now im trying to implement another aspect like this. im trying to have:

```
example.com/c/1234
```

instead of

```
example.com/c/postpage.php?link=1234
```

the directory seems to be messing with my .htaccess code and i cant even get close to it working.

any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the source of your *.htaccess* file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)$ /c/postpage.php?link=$1
```